# Progress-bar (Video Preloader)

Tags: apache-flex, progress-bar, components, flex-spark, videodisplay

I have a spark component VideoDisplay which displays a video.
I want to add a ProgressBar to it which will show load progress of the video and when the video is loaded ProgressBar to disappear. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Use `s:VideoPlayer` instead of `s:VideoDisplay`